# Dragging and Rotate an Rectangle in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, rotation, drag, rectangles

I try to build an application in JavaFX where I can drag the position und size of an rectangle. Also I would rotate the rectangle. My only way is spaghetti code.

[Here is a very helpfull example for the drag functionality / without rotate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26298873/resizable-and-movable-rectangle?answertab=active#tab-top)

But I can't extend this example with a rotate functionality!

Has somebody an idea?

Answer (score 1):

**Rotating with onMouseDragged event**

[image]

in this approach,  rectangle is placed so that its center fits the Group Node . Group will be used as cartecian coordinates . Almost any x,y point will draw a rectangle angle with its hypotenuse matching with the origen . getting that angle will allow subtract the angle given by onMousePressed to onMoussedragged. The result is the rotation of GroupNode itself in Z axis.
This approach does not have  division by zero implementation .

this is an example :

[image: rotating group javafx]

This is a single javafx app you can try

**App.java**

```
public class App extends Application {

private double startAngle;

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {

    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(400, 400, Color.STEELBLUE);
    r.setTranslateX(-200);
    r.setTranslateY(-200);

    Group group = new Group(r);

    group.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
        startAngle = aTanAngle(e.getX(), e.getY());

    });

    group.setOnMouseDragged((t) -> {

        double deltaAngle = aTanAngle(t.getX(), t.getY()) - startAngle;
        Rotate rotate = new Rotate(deltaAngle, Rotate.Z_AXIS);
        group.getTransforms().add(rotate);
    });

    var scene = new Scene(new StackPane(group), 640, 480);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

private double aTanAngle(double x, double y) {

    return Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(y / x));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch();
}

}
```